# How to avoid duplicates when python multiple except executes the same method?

Tags: python, exception, try-except, finally

I have the code block like below:

```
try:
   method()
except ErrorType1:
   todo()
   return
except ErrorType2 as e:
   todo()
   raise e
```

Basically for the two error types, I need to execute `todo()` first, then either `return` or `raise e`. Is it possible to just write `todo()` once? I was thinking using `finally` but don't think that actually works.

Comment: Your code seems clean enough to me as is, to be honest. Especially if you've refactored any repeated code into a dedicated function.

Comment: FWIW you may need to look at what exactly is being handled, you may want to reference [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7712651/python-how-to-avoid-code-duplication-in-exception-catching), [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/877440/try-except-except-how-to-avoid-repeating-code), and perhaps using a [context manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7108193/frequently-repeated-try-except-in-python). Ultimately you may need to take a real look at the context of your _actual_ code and see what fits better, but for a very simple case, what you got is extremely clear already.

Comment: " then either return or raise e. " So... some errors can be ignored but others can't? And when the error can't be ignored... we do the same cleanup work anyway? I find it a little hard to believe that these requirements actually make sense in context.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I could see a scenario where two types of error could occur, both of which require e.g. backing out a change to a database, but only one of which means you can't continue. Probably though it makes more sense to deal with the errors as they arise in `method`

Comment: Side-note: You want plain `raise`, not `raise e` here. `raise e` will act as if you're raising a new exception chained from the old one, creating multiple traceback dumps. Plain `raise` reraises the active exception as if it was never caught in the first place, so you don't get a pair of tracebacks, as if a new exception happened to be raised in the `except` block, separate from the original.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could catch both exceptions in one `except` clause, execute `todo` and then decide to do based on the exception type:

```py
try:
   method()
except (ErrorType1, ErrorType2) as e:
   todo()
   if isinstance(e, ErrorType1):
       return
   raise
```

Note - as pointed out by @ShadowRanger in the comments to the question - you should just use `raise` to re-raise the existing exception, using `raise e` will raise a second copy of it, resulting in the traceback including the line with `raise e` on it as well as the line where the original error occurred.

Answer (score 2):

If you have an common set of instructions (either encapsulated as a function or series of functions) that *must* be executed as part of an exception handling, consider using a context manager to encapsulate the common bits.  The following two results in identical outcome, albeit with different construction (one using `try..finally`, the other using `try..except`).

```
from contextlib import contextmanager
```

```
@contextmanager
def context1(method):
    print("starting context1")
    completed = False
    try:
        yield method()
        completed = True
    finally:
        if completed:
            commit()
        else:
            rollback()
    print("finished")
```

```
@contextmanager
def context2(method):
    print("starting context2")
    try:
        yield method()
    except Exception:
        rollback()
        raise
    else:
        commit()
    print("finished")
```

The latter one will not be able to deal with `KeyboardInterrupt` or other exceptions that subclass off `BaseException`, so for certain use case this is not exactly ideal, though it is included to follow suite of the question.  The first one is more of a response to the fact that you never appeared to have tried using `finally`, but rather simply thinking it does not actually works, and thus provided to show it can be used to achieve your goal (where only `todo()` in the question is executed if failure, through the use of a boolean variable).

In both cases, note how the common control flow is fully encapsulated inside the context manager, and usage is fairly straightforward like so such that all the unique extra cases can be done with another `try..except` block around the `with` context block.

```
try:
    with context1(f) as result:
        pass  # or use the result to do something
except Exception: ...
    # all the special unique cases be handled here.
```

To complete demo, more code is below; the `commit` and `rollback` functions I defined the following:

```
def commit():
    print("commit")

def rollback():
    print("rollback")
```

Now to test it, I defined the following helpers:

```
from functools import partial

class ErrorType1(Exception):
    pass

class ErrorType2(Exception):
    pass

def raise_e(e):
    raise e

subject = [
    object,
    partial(raise_e, ErrorType1),
    partial(raise_e, ErrorType2),
]
```

With the tests defined as such (replace `context1` with `context2` for the other demonstration):

```
for f in subject:
    try:
        with context1(f) as result:
            print('done - got result %r' % result)
    except ErrorType2:
        print("ErrorType2 will be raised")
        # raise  # uncomment to actually re-raise the exception
    except Exception as e:
        print("Exception trapped: %r raised by %r" % (e, f))
```

Note the output of both the above should look about like so (aside from `context1` vs `context2`):

```
starting context1
done - got result <object object at 0x7f20ccd3e180>
commit
finished
starting context1
rollback
Exception trapped: ErrorType1() raised by functools.partial(<function raise_e at 0x7f20ccb30af0>, <class '__main__.ErrorType1'>)
starting context1
rollback
ErrorType2 will be raised
```